# Return target informations from nested api json output

Tags: python

How could i improve the following code. This part was easy to implement but there is a lot of redondancy and i use pandas to return as dict which seems quite odd.

````
def pipeline_place_details(place_id, fields, lang):
    """Return a dataframe with useful information

    Args:
        place_id ([string]): Id retrieved from google api
        fields ([type]): Field retrieved from json output
    """
        fields = ['name', 'formatted_address', 'international_phone_number', 'website', 'rating', 'review']
        lang = 'fr'
        # details will give us a dict which is the result of serialized json returned from google api
        details = get_place_details(place_id, fields, "fr")
        try:
            website = details['result']['website']
        except KeyError:
            website = "" 
    
        try:
            address = details['result']['formatted_address']
        except KeyError:
            address = ""
            
        try:
            phone_number = details['result']['international_phone_number']
        except KeyError:
            phone_number = ""
            
        try:
            reviews = details['result']['reviews']
        except KeyError:
            reviews = []
        rev_temp = []
        for review in reviews:
            author_name = review['author_name']
            user_rating = review['rating']
            text = review['text']
            time = review['relative_time_description']
            rev_temp.append((author_name, user_rating, text, time))
        rev_temp_2 = pd.DataFrame(rev_temp, columns = ['author_name', 'rating', 'text', 'relative_time'])
        rev_temp_2['place_id'] = i
        rev_temp_2['address'] = address
        rev_temp_2['phone_number'] = phone_number
        rev_temp_2['website'] = website
        
        review_desc = review_desc.append(rev_temp_2, ignore_index = True)
    
    return review_desc.to_dict('records')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

**1. Getting data from dict**

When `details` is a `dict`, then instead of writing:

```
try:
    address = details['result']['formatted_address']
except KeyError:
    address = ""
```

you can do:

```
address = details.get('result', {}).get('formatted_address', '')
```

Second parameter of `.get` represents the default value which is returned when a dictionary doesn't contain a specific element

**2. Modularization**

Function `pipeline_place_details` is not short, so it might be a good idea to break it up into a smaller functions. Each time when you write a loop, it's worth to consider if moving body of the loop to a separate function will increase the code readability.

For example that part:

```
    author_name = review['author_name']
    user_rating = review['rating']
    text = review['text']
    time = review['relative_time_description']
    rev_temp.append((author_name, user_rating, text, time))
```

can be easiliy extracted to the new function:

```
def process_review(review):
        return (
            review['author_name'],
            review['rating'],
            review['text'],
            review['relative_time_description']
        )
```

and you can use it as below:

```
rev_temp = [process_review(review) for review in reviews]
```

**3. Variables naming**

Good code should be not only working and efficient but it should be also easy to read and understand. So it's a good rule to use really meaningful variable names. I belive that you can find better names than for example `rev_temp` or `rev_temp2`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I worked a bit on code and suggest that (i could encapsulate some parts as trivel suggest), what do you think ?

I directly work with dictionaries and try to avoid redundance letting the try except jon in get_from_dict function. It looks better (but perhaps perform more slowly ...).

````
def get_from_dict(dic, keys):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k, ""), keys, dic)

def parse_place_details(place_id):
        fields = ['name', 'formatted_address', 'rating', 'review','geometry']
        details = get_place_details(place_id, fields, 'fr')
        core_keys = {'adress':('result','formatted_address'),
                        'name':('result','name'),
                        'longitude':('result','geometry','location','lng'),
                        'latitude':('result','geometry','location','lat')}
        review_keys = {'author_name':('author_name',),
                       'user_rating':('rating',),
                       'text':('text',),
                       'time':('relative_time_description',)}
        results =[]
        core = {'place_id':place_id}
        for k,path in core_keys.items():
            core[k] = get_from_dict(details,path)
        reviews = get_from_dict(details,('result','reviews'))                     
        for review in reviews:
            descr ={k:get_from_dict(review,rkey) for k,rkey in review_keys.items()}
            descr.update(core)
            results.append(descr)       
        return results
    

```
````